# Geocoder gives certificate verify failed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl-certificate, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

I am using the geocoder gem on my rails web application to get the latitude and longitude of addresses. Every time I create a new Employee I want to get the latitude and longitude from the address inserted. Every time I attempt to great an employee or update I get the following error.
**SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed**
I have read multiple links and they all say to run the command "gem update --system", but this command has not helped correct the issue.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I'll start debugging this by removing rails from the middle, use Curl and try to use Geocoder's api to fetch the data you want. Is your server's date and time accurate? You could share your code also, it's hard to think what's wrong if you don't show what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple solution. I had to update my ruby to the most current version. I was running ruby 2.3.3. I updated to ruby 2.5.3. This resolved the issue for me.